# go build: no Go files in /msfs2020-go-master

Tags: go, compilation

Im trying to rebuild a golang github repository to apply some minor changes.

The go application Im trying to modify is the following https://github.com/lian/msfs2020-go
Please use the provided github link to inspect the file tree.

I used the master branch and extracted it to `/user/Documents/msfs2020-go-master`

If I call `go build` from `/user/Documents/msfs2020-go-master` the output equals: `no Go files in /user/Documents/msfs2020-go-master`

I tried deleting the `go.mod` and recreating it with `go mod init github.com/lian/msfs2020-go` followed with a `go mod tidy`
but still `no Go files in /user/Documents/msfs2020-go-master`

Here the current `go.mod`

```
module github.com/lian/msfs2020-go

go 1.16

require github.com/gorilla/websocket v1.4.2
```

And here the `go.sum`

```
github.com/gorilla/websocket v1.4.2 h1:+/TMaTYc4QFitKJxsQ7Yye35DkWvkdLcvGKqM+x0Ufc=
github.com/gorilla/websocket v1.4.2/go.mod h1:YR8l580nyteQvAITg2hZ9XVh4b55+EU/adAjf1fMHhE=
```

The master was build with 1.14 and Im using 1.16 golang.
All my test go applications/modules run/build/install fine at a "Hello World" developing level.

What did I do wrong? I gladly accept any input and will provide additional information's if requested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `go build` builds the package in the current working directory. The command reports an error because there is not a package at the root of the repository.

Fix by building the package containing the command.  Any of the following will work from the root of the repository:

```
go build ./vfrmap
```

or

```
cd vrfrmap
go build
```

or

```
go build github.com/lian/msfs2020-go/vfrmap
```

See also the file [build-vfrmap.sh](https://github.com/lian/msfs2020-go/blob/master/build-vfrmap.sh).

Comment: thank you, the misassumption that where the go.mod is located I need to build as well was critical
now my fork is working like a charm thanks again